# After gunzipping a tar.gz file and gzipping it again, the size of the tar.gz file changed a little bit

Tags: tar, gzip

Could someone please explain me why that was the case?

Comment: Maybe you're gzipping with a different compression target (`-1`, `-9`) the second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gzip file format is specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952

However, different encoders may produce different representations of the same file that are both acceptable, so if the tar file was zipped by different encoders the (zipped) file size could differ.